# How to change asp:ImageButton to type="submit" button?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have the following in a DNN module

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddItem" CssClass="add-item-btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="add_to_cart.gif" />
```

I need to change this be a regular type="submit" button.

I have tried changing it to a asp:HyperLink but I assume that it is connected to something else, hence the reason the page breaks?

Many thanks

EDIT:

I need to skin the button with css and it is not skinnable as a ImageButton.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnClientClick property to manually submit the form using JS:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddItem" CssClass="add-item-btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="add_to_cart.gif" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); return false;" />
```

Here 'myForm' is the ID of your form.

Comment: Thanks Marceln. I actually need to skin button using css and I cannot change the current image it uses, hence the reason I need to use something else. It seems to be binding to something though which might be the reason it is breaking the page.

Answer (score 0):

The control you're looking for is `<asp:Button>`, however, as you seem to have run into, you probably won't be able to change the control's type without making changes (probably very small) to the code-behind file.